# Using preg_replace inside tag

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I would like to change all url img src tag value from one string to the second like this:

```
   $str1 = "< img src="//d3kq20n0vvk93.cloudfiojiojront.net/cbbcadjiojoijc470efd702jijiojoijiojioc4.jpg" alt="">";
```

to:

```
  $str2 = "< img src="//d3kq20n0vvk93.cloudfiojiojront.net/cbbcadjiojoijc470efd702jijiojoijiojioc4.jpg?ttl=3600/" alt="">";
```

I tried this way but it doesn't work inside src="" tag:

```
   print preg_replace('/<img\s.*?\bsrc="(.*?)".*?>/si', "$0?ttl=3600", $str);
```

How can i resolve it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `$0` refers to the whole match *(from `<img` until `>`)* and you will obtain something like this `<img...>?tll=3600`.

What you need is to only change the src content, you can:

- use capturing groups:

  `echo preg_replace('~(<img\s.*?\bsrc=".*?)(".*?>)~si', '$1?ttl=3600$2', $str);`
- use [`\K`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) *(that resets the begining of the match from match result)* and a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) *(that only performs a check and is not part of the match result)*

  `echo preg_replace('~<img\s.*?\bsrc=".*?\K(?=".*?>)~si', '?ttl=3600', $str);`

However, keep in mind that the HTML code can be full of traps *(attribute between single quotes or no quotes at all, img tags with no src attribute, undefined number of spaces around the equal sign, attribute value or text content that contains the string `src="`...)*. This is the reason why, the cleanest solution is to use a specific tool to deal with HTML.

An example with DOMDocument:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($str);
$imgNodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach($imgNodes as $imgNode) {
    if ($imgNode->hasAttribute('src') && !empty($src = $imgNode->getAttribute('src')))
        $imgNode->setAttribute('src', $src . '?ttl=3600');
}
$result = $dom->saveHTML();
```

If you treat a piece of HTML and not a whole document, and if your PHP version is greater or equal than 5.3.6, you can replace the last line with:

```
$result = $dom->saveHTML($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0));
$result = substr($result, 6, -7);
```